# Why will the FDMA usually be used in transmitting analog signal,not in digital signal?

Tags: digital-communications

I saw this in the WiKi:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-division_multiple_access

FDMA can be used with both analog and digital signal but it generally used with analog signal

Why?Don't we usually transmit the digital signal now?why don't we usually use FDMA to transmit digital signal but analog?

[image]

Comment: In FDMA you need to separate the subchannels to avoid power leakage. This makes it bandwidth inefficient. OFDMA is a more efficient way because it doesn't require these separations by making sure the subcarriers are orthogonal to each others.

Comment: And says who it's generally used to transmit analog signals? Most signals transmitted these days are digital.

Comment: @BlackMath WIKI said that,i have the same thinking with you,i also think Most signals transmitted these days are digital,why does FDMA generally used with analog signal

Comment: Wiki is not a reliable source and I cannot think of a good reason why FDMA would be used generally with analog signals. Maybe because it was used when the communication was still analog? FDMA is not an efficient multiple access schemes, and nowadays it's not used in the standards. It's used sometimes in theory to study systems, though. So, I don't think the statement is correct.